# How to update a keyboard layout DLL on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Information about keyboard layout is stored in keyboard layout DLLs on Windows. One can make a custom layout using a tool like Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). It creates the dynamical library and also an installer which places the DLL at a right place and also puts necessary information to registry so the layout can be used.

Now my question. How can one update his custom layout? One could uninstall the layout and install the new version which effectively replaces the DLL file. However this alone doesn't work because it seems that the old copy of the DLL stays loaded somewhere and is used when one sets the layout instead of loading new version. So is there a way how to tell the system that its “keyboard layout cache” is invalid? Of course I could reboot the whole system but I'd like to avoid it as it's annoying and seems to be poor design to reboot whole system just to reload a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

A mechanism exists for forcing unused DLLs to be unloaded, meant mostly
for debugging shell extension.

From the article [Debugging with the Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> The Shell automatically unloads any DLL when its usage count is zero,
>   but only after the DLL has not been used for a period of time. This
>   inactive period might be unacceptably long at times, especially when a
>   Shell extension DLL is being debugged. You can shorten the inactive
>   period by adding the following information to the registry.

1. Open the registry editor (Start -> Run -> Regedit)
2. Scroll to:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
3. Click on Edit -> New, then DWORD Value
4. Create the DWORD value named `AlwaysUnloadDll`
5. Right-click this value, then choose Edit
6. Set the value data to 1, and then click OK.
7. Close the Registry Editor and restart the computer.
8. Now unused DLLs will be removed upon the closure of programs.

Running always with this setting can slow down your computer,
because Windows will keep on loading and unloading the same DLLs when programs are run.
It is recommended to only use it when editing a font.

As a further remark, I do not know whether this setting also works with font DLLs.
You will have to experiment and see.